# Expected Declaration Specifiers "NSRangeException"

Tags: iphone, exception

I had this in my try-catch-finally and it compiles ok.

```
@catch (NSException *e) {
.....
}
```

...but when I tried to catch NSRangeException: I got error.

```
@catch (NSRangeException *ne) {
.....
}
```

The error is:

```
Expected declaration specifiers: NSRangeExpection
```

(*TechZen says -- this presumably a typo for:*)

```
Expected declaration specifiers: NSRangeException
```

I did later to import "Funcation/NSException.h", but it didn't remove the error.

Answer (score 2):

This error can be caused nesting errors in the code preceding the line. It may have nothing to do with the line itself. Check and/or post the code above the line where the error occurs.

If the error message you posted is the actual message you got back, then you have a simple typo of writing NSRangeExpected for NSRangeException.

---

### Update:

Okay, looking over it again, the answer is simple and I just missed it. `NSException` is a class but `NSRangeException` is a name defined in a string constant:

```
extern NSString *NSRangeException;
```

... which simply returns a string of "NSRangeException".

Obviously, the `@catch` is expecting to receive a `NSException` object but gets a NSString object instead.

You can setup a `@catch` to accept a string like this:

```
@catch(NSString *stringException){...
```

or

```
@catch(id idException){...
```

... but usually there is no reason to.

You use NSRangeException and the other exception names to test against the `name` of the `NSException` instance that the `@catch` catches.

Comment: I changed nothing but NSException to NSRangeException. That's why I ruled out the possible of preceding lines causing the problem.

Yes, it was a typo.

I have changed my code so I no longer have the source.

Comment: I get the same error - just change NSException to NSRangeException makes the exact same problem ("Expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'NSRangeException')

Comment: Yes, I made a careless mistake. I missed something simple and I apologize. See my update for the correct answer.